# Configure Silex Routes with optional parameters

Tags: routes, silex

I have configured these 2 routes

```
$app->match ( '/controller/param/{country}/{q}', "demo.controller:demoAction" )->value ( 'country', 'de' )->value('q', '')->bind ( 'demo_action_with_country' );
$app->match ( '/controller/param/{q}', "demo.controller:demoAction" )->value ( 'q', '' )->bind ( 'demo_action_without_country' );
```

However - this does not work. If i call `/controller/param/Test-String` the route matches and returns content. If i call `/controller/param/DE/Test-String` i get *NotFoundHttpException*

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, i could easy fix that by my own. Here is my solution:

```
$app->match ( '/controller/param/{q}', "demo.controller:demoAction" )->value ( 'q', false )->bind ( 'demo_action_without_country' );
$app->match ( '/controller/param/{country}/{q}', "demo.controller:demoAction" )->value ( 'country', false )->value('q', '')->bind ( 'demo_action_with_country' );
```